# LINQ group collection by an arbitrary lattice

Tags: c#, linq

Apologies if I'm missing something very basic.

For a given lattice array in which lattice values represent the minimum for their bucket, what is the best way to group an array of values.

e.g.

```
double[] lattice = { 2.3, 2.8, 4.1, 4.7 };
double[] values  = { 2.35, 2.4, 2.6, 3, 3.8, 4.5, 5.0, 8.1 };

GroupByLattice(values, lattice);
```

such that GroupByLattice returns IGroupings that look like:

```
2.3 : { 2.35, 2.4, 2.6 }
2.8 : { 3, 3.8 }
4.1 : { 4.5 }
4.7 : { 5.0, 8.1 }
```

**edit:**

I'm green enough with LINQ queries that this is the best I can some up with:

```
values.GroupBy( curr => lattice.First( lat => curr > lat) )
```

Issues with this:

- Everything ends up in the first bucket - I can understand why (of course the first bucket satisfies the case for each after) but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around these in-place operations to get the predicate that I actually want.
- I suspect that having a LINQ query inside of a LINQ query will not be very performant

**Post-Mortem Solution and Results:**

Dmitry Bychenko provided a great answer, I just wanted to provide some followup for those who may come across this answer in the future. I had originally been trying to solve: [How can I simplify a huge dataset for plotting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571609/how-can-i-simplify-a-huge-dataset-for-plotting)

For starters, my first attempt was actually pretty close. With my lattice being already ordered I simply needed to change a `.First( ... )` to a `.Last( ... )`

i.e.

```
    values.GroupBy( curr => lattice.Last( lat => curr > lat) )
```

That's all well and good, but was curious about how much better Dmitry's solution would perform. I tested it with a random set of 10000 doubles, with a lattice at a 0.25 spacing. (I pulled out the `.Select(...)` transform from Dmitry's solution to keep it fair)

The average of 20 runs spit out the result:

```
Mine: 602ms
Dmitrys: 3ms
```

**Uh ... WOW!** That's a 200x increase in speed. *200x!* I had to run this a few times and inspect in the debugger just to be certain that the LINQ statement was evaluating before the timestamp (Trusty `.ToArray()` to the rescue). I'm going to say it now, anyone who's looking to accomplish this same task should most certainly use this methodology

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing that `lattice` is *sorted* (it's easy to sort the array with `Array.Sort(lattice)`) you can use `Array.BinarySearch`:

```
  double[] lattice = { 2.3, 2.8, 4.1, 4.7 };
  double[] values = { 2.35, 2.4, 2.6, 3, 3.8, 4.5, 5.0, 8.1 };

  var result = values
    .GroupBy(item => {
      int index = Array.BinarySearch(lattice, item);

      return index >= 0 ? lattice[index] : lattice[~index - 1];
    })
    .Select(chunk => String.Format("{0} : [{1}]", 
       chunk.Key, String.Join(", ", chunk)));
```

Test

```
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome

```
  2.3 : [2.35, 2.4, 2.6]
  2.8 : [3, 3.8]
  4.1 : [4.5]
  4.7 : [5, 8.1]
```

Comment: You'll need to do the inversion for non-exact matches *before* the grouping, else having an exact match will result in it being in its own group, rather than in the group for that match.  It's also something that realistically should be pulled out into a named method, rather than trying to do something like that inline.

Comment: This is cool--easy to plug in and test and seems to work in a variety of different cases. I'm just going to take a few minutes wrap my head around what's happening here before I accept, but this is already starting to make LINQ as a whole make more sense to me.

Comment: @Servy: I see, thank you! When working with *floating point* the exact equality is the case which can easily be overseen.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Answer edited, this is an incredibly fast solution compared to what I was trying to do!

Comment: @darkpbj: asymptotic is the thing that rules on the large scale. Binary search is only `log(N)` when enumerating (`Last` and alike) is `O(N)`

Answer (score 0):

If you ever need it faster, you can iterate the arrays only once if both of them are sorted:

```
double[] lattice = { 2.3, 2.8, 4.1, 4.7 };
double[] values = { 2.35, 2.4, 2.6, 3, 3.8, 4.5, 5.0, 8.1 };

var result = new List<double>[lattice.Length];  // array of lists

for (int l = lattice.Length - 1, v = values.Length - 1; l >= 0; l--) // starts from last elements
{
    result[l] = new List<double>(values.Length / lattice.Length * 2); // optional initial capacity of the list

    for (; v >= 0 && values[v] >= lattice[l]; v--)
    {
        result[l].Insert(0, values[v]);
    }
}
```